# Do I need to apply a license to my website?

Tags: licenses

I am currently developing my own personal website. The website content will basically be like a personal blog. Please refer below for the website content.

- I will post some of my personal interests, such as knowledge sharing
  and other interesting stuff, or maybe share a YouTube video that I
  found interesting.
- I plan to implement Google Ads to earn some passive income.

However, I am not sure if my website requires any licenses. Is it ok my website remain unlicensed? Since it will be free for all users, I do not plan to charge any fee for visitors to my website. I try to search online, and some people are suggesting the Creative Commons licenses. Do I need those?

Comment: There is a possibility that you may be confusing licensing with certificates.  Your site may still require a SSL certificate.

Comment: I am aware of the SSL certificate, and I surely will implement SSL for my website. As of now, I am unsure of the copyright licensing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is **no, you do not have to add a license to your website.** Only add a license if you wish to grant the general public the legal ability to copy and re-use your content without your permission.

By applying a [Creative Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons) license to your website, you would be explicitly permitting the general public to make copies of your website and re-host them anywhere else on the internet (with attribution). If you want to encourage people to freely copy and paste the contents of your website around the internet without your permission, you could consider such a license. Note that there are several flavors of the license (SA, ND, NC) that grant different freedoms and impose different restrictions.

If on the other hand you wish to send a message that you *don't* want anybody to copy or re-post your content without your permission, it may be best to put a copyright notice in the footer and leave it at that. In this case, people will still be legally allowed to share your content by posting links to your website<sup>[1]</sup>, but they will be prohibited from ripping and re-posting your content wholesale onto other websites.

As a side note, if you're planning to implement Google Ads, do be aware that [your website will need a privacy policy](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1348695?hl=en).

<sup>[1] According to my best knowledge of the law in all countries that I am familiar with. But I am not a lawyer.</sup>

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It was very helpful to me as it gave an insight into the usage of Creative Commons and Google Ads! I will try to study more about Creative Commons and Google Ads so that I can understand more about them.

Answer (score 1):

(Maybe its different if you live in a very repressive country), but in most parts of the world, no, you do not need a license for a website.

You do need to make sure you have the right to use all content on your website.  Where you generate the content yourself thats not an issue, but you do need to make sure that any images you get are appropriately licensed.  (This can vary from free to a one off payment - it really depends on the source of the images.   As at today, it is generally accepted that images/text generated by AI are also free to use but that might change and its best to check with the entity that controls the AI tool)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will ensure that I get appropriate licensing for any resources that I do not own.